# XSLT transformation with XSLT 1.0 in Mule ESB

Tags: xslt-1.0, mule

Is there a  way to use XSLT 1.0 processing in Mule 3.4.0 standalone? I did some googling. But did not find any answers.

Answer (score 0):

If by processing you mean "transformation", the answer is a resounding yes: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/XSLT+Transformer

Answer (score 0):

In case you dont want to use XSLT transfromer, you can also have a custom Java component or transformer in your mule flow and write java transformation logic using TransformerFactory.

Thanks KJ

Answer (score 0):

Mule has an XSLT transformer out of the box that you can use in your flows, and yes it supports XSLT 1.0. Check out this tutorial: http://marcotello.com/mule-esb/using-the-xslt-transformer-in-mule-esb/